# For $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is the $n$th power of a hermitian operator always hermitian?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, linear-algebra

It would seem to me that $\hat{Q}^n$ being a hermitian operator when $\hat{Q}$ is one, with $n$ being a positive integer, is not true in general. After all: if $n$ is uneven then it is impossible to split the operator into the product of two of the same operators raised to the same power, like so:
$$\hat{Q}^n = \hat{Q}^{n/2}\hat{Q}^{n/2}$$
And since two different hermitian operators will not necessarily commute they might not be hermitian in that case.

Yet I've found some suggestion online that a hermitian operator raised to a power $n$ is always hermitian? Is this true, or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: I see. Thank you, that basically answers my question. I'll attempt a proof of it, which should be a lot easier now that I know what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3):

> And since two different hermitian operators will not necessarily commute they might not be hermitian in that case.

That may be the case, but an operator commutes with all its powers, i.e. $[A^m,A^n] = 0$ for any operator $A$ and any $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$. This follows simply from $[A,A] = 0$ and writing out the definition of $A^n$.

Comment: Right, because $A^nA^m=A^mA^n=A^{n+m}$. Seems pretty obvious in hindsight. In any case thank you, that's the proof basically done.

Comment: I suppose one must suppose there are no issues of domains (and related self-adjoint extensions) here.  It could be the domain of powers of an operator is not the same as that of the operator (as $\hat p$ on a finite line).

Comment: @ZeroTheHero There are no domain issues; for any real-valued function $f$ (so in particular for $f(x) = x^n$), $f(A)$ is self-adjoint if $A$ is self-adjoint, cf. https://mathoverflow.net/a/95336.

Comment: @ACuriousMind somehow I never realized this…. it seems so obvious now.